# XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

I have an UTF-8 encoded xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

When using below version of xml reader. I am assuming this uses UTF-8 enoding to parse xml file.

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUri))
```

I am getting below exception.

```
System.Xml.XmlException occurred
  HResult=-2146232000
  LineNumber=18750
  LinePosition=13
  Message=Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 18750, position 13.
```

But when using  below version of xmlreader

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(inputUri,Encoding.UTF8)))
```

The xml gets parsed successfully. Why such differences between these two versions given both uses same encoding to parse the given xml file??

PS: I am pretty much sure the first version uses UTF-8 endoding.

Below is the snippet from **XmlTextReaderImpl.cs** whose instance is returned by the first version.

```
        private void SetupEncoding( Encoding encoding ) {
            if ( encoding == null ) {
                Debug.Assert( ps.charPos == 0 );
                ps.encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                ps.decoder = new SafeAsciiDecoder(); // This falls back to UTF-8 decoder
            }
}
```

Comment: Which .net version you are using?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer in [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/267fbe9a-dd78-4c68-9840-d0467fdbd456/xmlexception-invalid-character-in-the-given-encoding?forum=csharpgeneral).

"XmlReader will mark any illegal character as illegal because the XML format is broken.

On the second case, because StreamReader is a general purpose Text reader, when it encounters data that is not within range defined by Encoding, it replace the character with a [replacement fallback](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/decoderreplacementfallback.cs). And therefore when you pass the resulting stream to XmlReader, all characters it can see now falls in legal range defined by the encoding."

Answer (score 0):

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUri))
```

The above will use the encoding of the `XmlReader` and will ignore the encoding declaration of the file.

Which is why the exception occurs, and is why the second method works - as you provide a `UTF-8` encoding to use.

N.B. I *think* that the default encoding is UTF-16